# Creating "Inner Buffer" using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, buffer

I am currently searching for how to create an "Inner Buffer" in ArcGIS for Desktop?

I have a lot of polygons (houses) in one feature class, and one big polygon (in another feature class).

I want so select all houses contained in that one big polygon within a distance to the outer border (e.g. 1000 meters).

*Select Layer By Location* could be one possibility to solve this but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The steps to do this are:

1. Select your layer by clicking on it
2. From the `Editor` toolbar, select `Start Editing`
3. On the Editor Menu, select `Buffer`
4. Write a Negative `Distance` Amount to create an inside buffer...

**Without Inner Buffer:**

[image: unbuffer]

**With Inner Buffer:**

[image: with buffer]

Answer (score 9):

**Select by Location with negative 1000m buffer, switch selection, select by location "Within" again from reversed selection set**

**Step 1:**

- Selection method: Select Features From **(default)**
- Target Layer: Houses
- Source Layer: Big Polygon
- Spatial Selection Method: Target layers(s) features intersect the Source layer feature **(default)**
- Apply a search distance = **-1000m**

**Step 2:**

Once you obtain the selection set (only features inside the "big polygon" and that are located 1000m from the boundary will be now selected): SWITCH SELECTION

There are a few ways to switch (reverse) selection; for example, right click on the layer in the TOC --> Selection --> Switch Selection

**Step 3:**

Use Select by location on the reversed selection set:

- **Selection method: Select from currently selected features in**
- Target Layer: Houses
- Source Layer: Big Polygon
- **Spatial Selection Method: Target layers(s) features are completely within the Source layer feature**
- **NO Buffer** is applied in this search

The resulting selection set will contain all features that are completely within the "Big Polygon" and whose boundary is less then 1000m from its boundary.

Comment: +1 since this can be easily scripted or modeled in ModelBuilder; for step 2, the Select Layer by Attributes tool can be used to just switch the selection