# Selecting GPS point closer to boundary of polygon in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3

I would like to capture the gps points which are closer the polygon boundary (inside), not point in polygon.

I have arcgis arcinfo v9.3.

i can do with inner buffer of the polygon and intersection and finding the remaining gps points.  Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Select By Location:**

Select all the points intersecting the polygon and indicate a NEGATIVE search distance.

Reverse the resulting selection set.

Run another Select by Location on the reversed selection set but use "Within"

Similar topic discussed [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24902/create-inner-buffer-in-arcgis/24908#24908)